# Using Core Data After NSBatchDeleteRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

In my app, when I'm refreshing the contents of an entity from a web service, I delete all records in my Core Data and insert all the new ones. However, a lot of the time the records aren't removed from the context, even if I call the context again. So when I save, the old ones remain and I just end up stacking on top of the existing ones getting lots of duplicates. How can I completely clear the context so I don't need to worry about duplicates?

```
    var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "V_ServiceDetails")

    // Clear all
    let request = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do {
        let result = try context.execute(request)
    } catch {}

    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    // Add new ones
    for svc in self.svcs {
        let result = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "V_ServiceDetails", into: context)

        result.setValue(svc.Car_VIN, forKey: "car_VIN")
        result.setValue(svc.Cust_Veh_ID, forKey: "cust_Veh_ID")

        do { try context.save() } catch {}
    }
```

Comment: After you delete the the items in the context. Can you try saving the context `context.save()`

Comment: @TheAppMentor I have updated it to:
`do {
            let result = try context.execute(request)
            try context.save()
        } catch {}` but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function below:

```
func deleteAll() {

    // Managed Object Context
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    // Save the changes of the Managed Object Context before executing the Batch Delete Request
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Error
        }
    }

    // Craete a Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ManagedObject> = ManagedObject.fetchRequest()

    // Initiliaze the Batch Delete Request
    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest.init(fetchRequest: fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

    // Configure the Batch Delete Request
    batchDeleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeCount

    do {

        // Execute the Batch Delete Request
        try managedObjectContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest)

        // Reset the Managed Object Context
        managedObjectContext.reset()

        // try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        // If you have a Table View? Use this function
        // self.tableView.reloadData()

    } catch {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple docs on batch delete](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html), it says that the delete is done directly at the SQL level. The deletions are **NOT REFLECTED** in objects that you have in memory so you need to update your app after the deletion. See the section **Updating Your Application After Execution** on the linked page.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
var e = 1
    
    while e <= self.items!.count {
        
        self.context.delete(self.items![e - 1])
        
        // Save the data
        do {
            try self.context.save()
            
        }
        catch {
            
            
        }
        
        e = e + 1
        
        
    }
```